# Once logged in to the website how do to run other scenarios in the same session

Tags: cucumber

I am using cucumber, Watir WebDriver and Ruby for testing. In my feature file I have something like this:

```
Feature:....
Background:....
Scenario: 1
   some steps
Scenario 2
   some steps
...
```

After the Background logged in to the website how can I run Scenario 1 then 2 in a same session? Currently Scenario 2 will start a new browser.

Thanks

Comment: Move background steps to secnario 1 and don't open new browser if existing session is not closed and don't close the browser for each scenario. You should have logic for the same.

Comment: You need to use the concept of a SharedWebDriver that will remain open for all scenarios and it will close using a java shutdown hook. - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/examples/java-webbit-websockets-selenium/src/test/java/cucumber/examples/java/websockets

Comment: Thank you all I will try all your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Each scenario is a separate test that starts from scratch. Trying to link scenarios together is a classic cucumber anti-pattern, don't repeat this mistake.